# search for first pattern and copy the string inside the ( ) into the 3rd field in lines where the second pattern found

Tags: sed, awk, perl

Here are my spec:

1. first search for "#firstpattern("
2. copy the content inside the  ( ) to the 3rd field inside the ( ) of all lines where the "secondpattern" found.
3. remove the entire line with the "#firstpattern" at
4. I'd like to process all files "files.txt" in the same folder. no need to save backups.

A sed command but others should be fine.

datain.txt :

```
...some lines...

#firstpattern(stringtobecopied)
...some lines...
secondpattern something here (something, some text here,  someting else).
secondpattern something here (something, some text here,  someting else).
```

dataout.txt :

```
...some lines...
secondpattern something here (something, some text here, stringtobecopied, someting else).
secondpattern something here (something, some text here, stringtobecopied, someting else).
```

Comment: I assume that you are trying to modify source code.  Instead check if your IDE provides the capability to refactor...

Comment: Line-oriented tools like sed are not very easy to use for multi-line edits like that. You'll probably need a script.

Comment: Note that a regular expression is incapable of handling this job if there are nested parentheses inside the ().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script does what you want. It's pretty verbose for clarity. You can probably simplify it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#

use strict;
use warnings;

my $first_pattern = '#firstpattern\(';
my $second_pattern = 'secondpattern';

my $string_obtained = '';

while (<>) 
{
    if ($_ =~ /$first_pattern([^\)]*)\)/)
    {
        $string_obtained = $1;
        next;
    }

    if ($string_obtained ne "" && $_ =~ /^$second_pattern/)
    {
        $_ =~ s/([^,]*,[^,]*,)/$1 $string_obtained,/;
    }
    print $_;
}
```

Comment: Of course, as stated by @glenn-jackman, regexps are limited. If one of the fields between ',' is a string containing a ',' for example, the script will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Preferred solutions, best is first:

1. As stated in comments: if you're trying to refactor source code, use an editor with refactoring/macro abilities.
2. Use a script like the one by *lgeorget*. Adapt it as needed to fit your constraints.
3. Mess around with one-liners because it's fun.

Here's just for the fun of writing it. Needs `bash` (uses process substitution). Assumes no other parentheses or commas in data except as shown in your original example.

```
sed "s/\([^,]*,[^,]*,\)/\1 $(awk -F'[()]' '/^#firstpattern/ {print $2}' datain.txt),/g" < <(grep -v '#firstpattern' datain.txt)
```

Output:

```
...some lines...

...some lines...
secondpattern something here (something, some text here, stringtobecopied,  someting else).
secondpattern something here (something, some text here, stringtobecopied,  someting else).
```